# creating UML charts by Pylint/pyreverse within Jupyter labs / console

Tags: python, uml, jupyter, pylint

I have tried many examples and it fails, I am looking for a simple flow for class dependencies UML chart

pip Installed pylint and graphviz and imported,

the simplest line I found was:

```
 pyreverse -o png -p Project /path/train_loop.py
```

got: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (pointing at the png of last statement)

i generally work with jupyter labs - i am looking for a solution at the console, notebook or maybe a module that performs this.

Comment: note that your sample command here should be run on the command line, not in a jupyter notebook. might be why you got an error? In any case, I too am looking for a good way to produce uml diagrams within a jupyter notebook, will leave an answer if I find one.

Answer (score 4):

In its simplest form, running on a colab notebook, and for datetime as an example:

```
!pip install --q pylint
!pyreverse -o png datetime
```

Generates the following png:

[image]